# Save an Excel sheet as PDF programatically through powerbuilder

Tags: ole, powerbuilder

There is a requirement to save an excel sheet as a pdf file programmatically through `powerbuilder` (Powerbuilder 12.5.1).

I run the code below; however, I am not getting the right results. Please let me know if I should do something different.

```
 OLEObject  ole_excel;
 ole_excel = create OLEObject;

 IF ( ole_excel.ConnectToObject(ls_DocPath) = 0 ) THEN
      ole_excel.application.activeworkbook.SaveAs(ls_DocPath,17);
      ole_excel.application.activeworkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,ls_DocPath);
 END IF;
 ....... (Parsing values from excel)
 DESTROY ole_excel;
```

I have searched through this community and others for a solution but no luck so far. I tried using two different commands that I found during this search. Both of them return a null object reference error. It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to have a reference to the 'activeworkbook'.  This would be of type OLEobject so the declaration would be similar to: OLEobject lole_workbook.

Then you need to set this to the active work book.  Look for the VBA code on Excel (should be in the Excel help) for something like a 'getactiveworkbook' method.  You would then (in PB) need to do something like
`lole_workbook = ole_excel.application.activeworkbook`

This gets the reference for PB to the activeworkbook.  Then do you saveas and etc. like this `lole_workbook.SaveAs(ls_DocPath,17)`

Comment: Thank you Matt. The problem was, powerbuilder did not know which worksheet/workbook it needs to save. There are 3 sheets and I needed to save the first one. Your answer helped in the right direction.

Comment: Just one more thing, I do the following to quit the excel and close the excel sheet. After I close the application, I tried to open the Excel sheet to edit it in MS Excel. The MS excel opens alright, but it is empty(Not even grid lines). I am assuming that I did something wrong while closing the excel.
<pre><code>ole_excel.application.workbooks(1).Save();
ole_excel.Application.Quit;
ole_excel.DisconnectObject();</pre></code>

Answer (score 0):

`workBook.saveAs()` documentation says that saveAs() has the following parameters:

`SaveAs(Filename, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)`

we need the two first params:

`FileName` - full path with filename and extension, for instance: `c:\myfolder\file.pdf`

`FileFormat` - predefined constant, that represents the target file format.
According to google (MS does not list `pdf` format constant for XLFileFormat), FileFormat for `pdf` is equal to `57`

so, try to use the following call:

```
ole_excel.application.activeworkbook.SaveAs(ls_DocPath, 57);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rafael. Still it does not work after using the code 57. I am still receiving the null object reference error on that particular line. Do I need a special dll or something for performing this SaveAs?

Comment: According to [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb407651(v=office.12).aspx) (see section "4") it is requred to have "Save as PDF add-in" installed. Otherwise `Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat` generates an exception. Hope this helps.

Comment: here is the link for the add-in: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7

Comment: I have installed this add in. Still does not work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Consider printing your excel file as PDF. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888359/creating-pdf-file-in-powerbuilder