# Powerbuilder 12 cannot save as pdf datawindow

Tags: pdf, powerbuilder, datawindow

I am running windows 2003 server.  I had no problems doing a dw_1.saveas for a pdf until about 2 weeks ago when the hosting company decided to do a software update on the server.  Now when I do a save as the file size is 0 kb.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did the hosting company give you any info on what the update included or maybe the KB number? I'm thinking you might could research the KB at Microsoft for a hint as to what might have happened.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  0 kb refers to the size of the file after saveas is executed.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting 0 byte files, running `PB Classic 12.5.1 build 4541 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64 bit`.  Based on the comments of both previous answers, I installed 32 bit `Ghostscript 9.1` to default location, verified that the registry entry was not there, then installed 64 bit Ghostscript 9.1 to default location, saw the registry values were there, then modified the registry to point to the 32 bit installation directory as follows:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\9.10]
"GS_DLL"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.10\\bin\\gsdll32.dll"
"GS_LIB"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.10\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.10\\lib;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.10\\fonts"
```

Save As PDF using Distill is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2: Another cause I've seen is mis-matched PowerBuilder DLLs and PBDs. Make sure that the runtime DLLs and PBDs on the server are the same as the ones on the machine where the app was built.

Edit: I re-read your question. A zero byte PDF usually indicates that PowerBuilder couldn't find GhostScript. Check the registry as described below, and check the folder GhostScript is installed in. Re-running the GhostScript installer should fix it. I'll leave the rest of the troubleshooting info in case anyone else needs it.

If you're using Distill, the problem could be that the server configuration was changed to require signed drivers. If so, you'll have to install the "Sybase DataWindow PS" printer with a signed driver. I find the 'HP 8150 Series PS' driver works pretty well. I wrote up directions in [Saving a datawindow as PDF in PB 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460930/saving-a-datawindow-as-pdf-in-pb-10-5/2463367#2463367).

You might get a useful error message if you try to print to Sybase DataWindow PS from Notepad. Another possibility is that the Registry entries that PowerBuilder uses to find GhostScript got clobbered. We had that on a couple of workstations. Here's what I have for Ghostscript 8.60 (The GhostScript installer creates these entries):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\8.60]
"GS_DLL"="C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs8.60\\bin\\gsdll32.dll"
"GS_LIB"="C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs8.60\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\gs\\fonts;C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs8.60\\Resource"
```

I used [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to troubleshoot problems with PowerBuilder's Save as PDF functionality.

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions but that has not resolved my issue.  I am not familiar with Process Explorer.  How do I use it to troubleshoot the issues with PDF's saving?

Comment: I started writing up troubleshooting with PE. As I was doing so, I thought of another possible cause. See Edit 2. If that's not it we'll drag out PE.

Comment: On Edit #2:  The dlls are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (PDF with 0 KB size) when I use Windows 2003 Server 64 bits and I resolve my problem like shown here :

=> At first, when I install Ghostscript 32 bits version, I see no entries in the Registry.

=> When I install a Ghostscript 64 bits version, there is no problem in the Registry, entries are created, but the system doesn't work (PDF is generated with 0 KB size)

=> I create a new directory with Ghosscript 32 bits version and I change the Registy entries

=> And then I uninstall the 64 bits version.

=> AND NOW, EVERYTHING IS OK !

Used Ghostscipt versions : gs904 for the 32 bits version and gs910 for the 64 bits one.